# How are the Erlang/OTP applications packaged?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

There's a list of [official Erlang/OTP applications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/applications.html). Will all of them come along with the latest Erlang/OTP installation? Otherwise, how to know  which of them are actually installed and continue to install the missing?

**@EDIT**

Many of the official applications are `deb`'ed individually on Ubuntu from [Erlang/OTP repos](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp) of Erlang Solutions (checking on `Installation using repository`), so `apt/deb` does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe all of them are in the installation (some may be excluded during compilation, if you are building from source). Perhaps not `ose`, which is OS-specific, so it won't work even if it is included.

Comment: Humm, have you any source for this information ? Or it's a random answer ?

Comment: I've installed the latest Erlang/OTP distro from Erlang Solutions. Some of the applications are reported missing when trying to run a third-party application.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin What I remember from building Erlang from source, never running into a missing application (though I never had to use all of them), etc. It might be wrong, admittedly, or depend on the OS/distribution.

Comment: @sof Sorry for misleading you, in this case. Which OS and which applications?

Comment: @Alexey Romanov It's from the latest Erlang/OTP distro on Ubuntu from Erlang Solutions that `rabbitmq` complains missing `[eldap,xmerl]`.

Comment: @sof The documentation for Ubuntu at https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp does say "Installing the `erlang` package automatically installs the entire OTP suite."

Comment: @sof They are also listed as dependencies in the standard Ubuntu repository http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/interpreters/erlang so it looks like they _should_ be installed by default.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov thanks. I looked into `/usr/lib/erlang/lib` and found lots missing there. How can the missing be installed afterwords?

Comment: @sof Perhaps you installed `erlang-base` (and possibly some more `erlang-` packages) instead of `erlang`? `dpkg-query -l 'erlang*'` should list all installed packages, then see which ones from packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/interpreters/erlang are missing and `sudo apt-get install erlang-xmerl erlang-eldap ...`.

Answer (score 2):

All of them are included in the standard release from erlang.org and from Erlang Solution, or if you download the source and build it yourself. Which are included in various OS specific packages is up to them.